# nginx error 403 - directory index is forbidden

Tags: nginx, flask, docker, gunicorn

I am trying to connect `docker nginx` with `docker flask`. Here is the structure of my project:

```
.
├── storage
│   ├── nginx
│   │   └── static
│   │       └── image.gif
└── web
    └── flask
        ├── app
        │   ├── run.py
        │   └── templates
        │       └── index.html
        ├── conf
        │   ├── nginx-default.conf
        │   ├── nginx-flask.conf
        │   └── requirements.txt
        └── Dockerfile
```

Although `curl 127.0.0.1:50` and `curl 127.0.0.1:80/static/image.gif` work fine, I get a '403 Forbidden' error when I do `curl 127.0.0.1`. More specifically, `nginx` gives the following error:

```
2016/03/05 17:54:37 [error] 8#8: *1 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
172.17.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2016:17:54:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0" "-"
```

I create the containers like this:

```
docker create \
-v $ROOT/web/flask/app/:/web/flask/app/ \
--name flask_data flask:0.1

docker run \
-d -p 127.0.0.1:50:50 \
--volumes-from flask_data \
--name flask_service flask:0.1

docker create \
-v $ROOT/storage/nginx/:/usr/share/nginx/html/ \
--name nginx_data nginx:1.9

docker run \
-v $ROOT/web/flask/conf/nginx-flask.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-flask.conf \
-v $ROOT/web/flask/conf/nginx-default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default \
-d -p 127.0.0.1:80:80 \
--volumes-from nginx_data \
--link flask_service:flask_service_alias \
--name nginx_service nginx:1.9
```

where, `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python-pip python-dev

COPY . /web/flask/

RUN pip install -r /web/flask/conf/requirements.txt

CMD gunicorn run:app --workers=4 --bind=0.0.0.0:50 --log-level=debug --timeout=43200 --chdir=/web/flask/app/
```

and `requirements.txt` is:

```
gunicorn==19.4.5
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Redis==0.1.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.1
Flask-MongoAlchemy==0.7.2
```

`nginx-default` is empty, and `nginx-flask` is:

```
server {

    listen          80;
    charset         utf-8;

    location /avatar {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/avatar;
    }

    location /scan {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/scan;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://flask_service_alias:50/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```

any ideas?

Comment: did you check your file/directory permission?

Comment: sure. permissions of all files and (sub-) directories are set to `drwxrwxr-x`.

Comment: /usr/share/nginx/html/ <-- including all the folders along this path ?

Comment: well, I mean the ones on the host machine (or in other words, all those listed above). the `/usr/share/nginx/html/` refers to the `nginx container`, so no idea about this. I assume I shouldn't touch this, right?

Comment: oh well you might give it a try by setting 755 for those folders too

Comment: ok. may I ask you to provide the required commands (access the docker and change the permissions)?  I am not that confident with dockers, yet!

Comment: ok. I access it with `docker exec -it nginx_service bash` and I saw that folder `html` and all of its subdirectories are set to `drwxrwxr-x  5 1000 1000`. is this ok?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like what might be going on is the `default.conf` file in the `nginx` image is taking over the `/` location. You nginx run command has:

```
-v $ROOT/web/flask/conf/nginx-default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default \
```

This should be overwriting the `default.conf` instead of just `default`. As it currently stands, it just adds another blank `default` file and leaves the default `default.conf` which has a location for `/`.

You static route does work because there is an explicit route in the `nginx-flask.conf` to `/static` and you call the file explicitly. You get a `403` on the `/` location because indexes are disabled by default (controlled by the `autoindex` option).

Comment: ohh dear. now I see. :) you are right. there are 3 files under `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` inside the nginx container (not just two)! how can I start the nginx container so as to avoid this behaviour? thank you so much!